# Hibernate правильный маппинг

Tags: база-данных, hibernate

Есть две сущности - каталог и метка(агрегатор дополнительных свойств каталога, вынесенных в отдельную сущность для удобства) Вроде бы правильный маппинг - one to one, но метка не уникальна для каждого отдельного каталога и два разных каталога могут иметь одинаковую метку. Какой маппинг правильный? Спасибо.

Comment: и как организовать внешние ключи в базе?

Comment: В первую очередь - покажите ваш код, чтобы не рассуждать гипотетически. Или вы ждёте телепатов, которые заочно погадают на вашем коде?

Comment: in catalog class

Comment: private Metka;

 @Override
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Metka.class)
 public Metka getMetka() {
  return metka;
 }

Comment: in metka class:

Comment: private List<Catalog> catalogs= new ArrayList<Catalog>();                                          @Override
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Catalog.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<Catalog> getcatalogs() {
        return catalogs;
    }

Comment: Я поставил минус за код в комментариях. Читать подобное невозможно из-за неправильных переносов строк, вряд ли бы вам понравился такой ответ. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править", можете внести правки прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо и на том...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Catalog
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "catalog", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Metka metka;

//Metka
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "metka")
    private Catalog catalog;
```

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/